# Angular and Laravel - Displaying the last record in the database gave me a wrong result

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing a Web Portal using Angular-7 as the frontend and Laravel-5.8 as the backend. I want to display the last data that was posted into the database:

Laravel

ApiController.php

```
public function showClient(Request $request)
{
    try{
         $client = Client::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();   
          return response()->json($client, 200);
        }
        catch(QueryException $e)
        {
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
            return response()->json($errorCode);
        }
}
```

api.php

```
Route::get('showClient', 'ApiController@showClient');
```

Angular

client.component.ts

```
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

  clientdetail = null;

  headers = {     //Token for API Authorization
    'Authorization' : this.token.get(),
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }


  constructor(
    private api: ApiService,
    private token: TokenService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private notify: SnotifyService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    this.api.get('showClient', this.headers).subscribe(
      data => {console.log(data), this.clientdetail = data; this.dataHandlerclientdetail(data)}
    );
  }

  dataHandlerclientdetail(data){
    console.log(data.data);
  }

}
```

When I loaded the page, I suppose to get the last data posted into the table but everything in the table was displayed.

Kindly guide me how do I get this resolved?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use last() method

```
public function showClient(Request $request)
{
    try{
         $client = Client::select('*')->get()->last();   
          return response()->json($client, 200);
        }
        catch(QueryException $e)
        {
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
            return response()->json($errorCode);
        }
}
```